# Every first element in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Tried posting this before but am going to try to re word it.

Lets say i have a multidimensional array, and I want to affect the first element in each one before moving onto the second element in each one.

I have an array of projects where the key is the order# and the value is the hours it takes to complete the order.

```
Array
(
[100 Series] => Array
    (
        [Order1] => 6
        [Order2] => 6
        [Order3] => 6
        [Order4] => 6
        [Order5] => 6
        [Order6] => 6
        [Order7] => 6
        [Order8] => 6
    )

[50 Series] => Array
    (
        [Order1] => 4
        [Order2] => 4
        [Order3] => 4
        [Order4] => 4
    )

)
```

I then have an array of people, with schedules and projects they can work on:

```
Array
(
[Eric Smith] => Array
    (
        [Schedule] => Array
            (
                [Monday] => 8
                [Tuesday] => 8
                [Wednesday] => 8
                [Thursday] => 8
                [Friday] => 6
                [Saturday] => 0
                [Sunday] => 0
            )

        [Projects] => Array
            (
                [0] => 100 Series
                [1] => 50 Series
            )

    )

)
```

I'd like to fill a work flow array with the day, project name, order# and then the persons name and hours they are working on said project, it would look something like this:

```
Array
(
[Monday] => Array
    (
        [100 Series] => Array
            (
                [Order1] => Array
                    (
                        [Eric Smith] => 6
                    )
             )
        [50 Series] => Array
            (
                [Order1] => Array
                    (
                        [Eric Smith] => 2
                    )
    )
[Tuesday] => Array
    (
        [50 Series] => Array
            (
                [Order1] => Array
                    (
                        [Eric Smith] => 2
                    )
            )
        [100 Series] => Array

                [Order2] => Array
                    (
                        [Eric Smith] => 6
                    )
            )
    )
```

So the orders array should look like this:

```
Array
(
[100 Series] => Array
    (
        [Order1] => 0
        [Order2] => 0
        [Order3] => 6
        [Order4] => 6
        [Order5] => 6
        [Order6] => 6
        [Order7] => 6
        [Order8] => 6
    )

[50 Series] => Array
    (
        [Order1] => 0
        [Order2] => 4
        [Order3] => 4
        [Order4] => 4
    )

)
```

Right now it's just moving through the first project array orders 1-8 then moving onto the second project. I'd like it to complete all the first elements in the orders->project array before moving onto the second in each.

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't tracking this in a relational database, and getting information about projects and their personnel via queries?

Comment: I will eventually. Just getting local data working first.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you posted the code that you are using now that's not working. I'm also not 100% clear on what exactly you want to do. And it seems like there's probably a better way you could implement the whole thing than with the multi-dim arrays, but to answer the question, this might work:

```
$index = 0;
start:
for ($i=0;i<count($projectArray);$i++){
    if (count($project)<$index)goto finished; //or maybe continue;
    //you may need some extra conditionals, but that depends on what you want to be terminating the loop
    $project = $projectArray[$i];
    $item = $project[$index]; //then do what you want with $item
}
$index++;
//if you are not finished
goto start;
finished:
//the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the first array in your post is called `$projects;` and your workflow array is called `$workflow;`

You will want the following:

```
// first loop $workflow and create an array that can be processed more easily
$data = array();
foreach($workflow as $day => $project){
    foreach($project as $projectName => $projectDetails){
            foreach($projectDetails as $orderNumber => $person){
                    foreach($person as $hours){
                            $data[$orderNumber][$projectName] = $hours;    
                    }
            }
    }
}

// print_r($data) shows new array that is ordered in terms of order => project => hours

// now update your $projects array with this $data
foreach($data as $key => $project){
    foreach($project as $projectName => $projectHours){
            $projects[$projectName][$key] -= $projectHours;
    }
}

// print_r($projects) to see that the project hours have decreased appropriately
```

I appreciate that the deeply nested foreach loops are not ideal, but neither is the methods in which you are trying to work. I think this makes the best out of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Look into array_walk_recursive.

You can use a callback that checks if the value isn't an array itself and is the first value of an array.

EDIT
array_walk_recursive seems to be useless since it does not pass any info regarding where you are in the array.
Here is my walk function:

```
class arr{

    /**
     * Iterate and traverse array and apply function to data
     * 
     * example:
     * $f = function($v, $k, $custom, $info){
     *      if(!is_array($v) && !obj::is($v)) {
     *          return $v." [ custom: {$custom['key']} ] [ level: ".$info['depth'].' | No '.$info['i'].' of '.$info['count']." ]";
     *      }
     *      return $v;
     *  };
     * 
     *  arr::walk($mixed,$f,['key'=>'value'],true)
     * 
     * @param array $array
     * @param function,array $callback
     * @param mixed $custom
     * @param integer,boolean $recursive
     * @param boolean $deduce
     * @param array $info
     * @return array
     */
    public static function walk(&$array, $callback, $custom = null, $recursive = true, $deduce = false, $info = [])
    {
        if (is_array($array)) {
            $return = null;
            if (array_key_exists('depth', $info)) {
                $info['depth'] ++;
            } else {
                $info['depth'] = 1;
            }
            $info['count'] = count($array);
            $info['i'] = 1;
            $r = $recursive;
            if (gettype($r) === 'integer') {
                $r--;
            }
            foreach($array as $k => &$v) {
                $inf = $info;
                if ($info['depth'] > 0) {
                    $inf['path'][] = $k;
                }
                if ($return = $callback($v, $k, $custom, $inf, $array)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (is_array($v) && $r > 0) {
                    $return = arr::walk($v, $callback, $custom, $r, $deduce, $inf);
                    if ($return) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $info['i'] ++;
            }
            return $return;
        }
    }    
}
```

Your implementations should look something like this:

```
$result = [];
arr::w($a, function($v,$k) use (&$result){
    if(is_array($v) && !empty($v)){        
        $r = array_values($v)[0];
        if(!is_array($r)){
            $result[] = $r;
        }
    }
}
);
```